# sum of numeric palindromes

Tags: python, palindrome

I'm stuck on a problem test.
The prompt is:

> A palindrome is a word, number, phrase, or another sequence of characters which
> reads the same backward as forward, such as madam, racecar, or the number
> 10801.
>
> What is the sum of all numeric palindromes that are less than 10,000?

My code so far is:

```
def is_numeric_palindrome(number):
    """

    :param number: an integer
    :return: true if number is a numeric palindrome
    """
    number_as_string = str(number)
    number_digit_length = len(number_as_string)

    for i in range(0, int(number_digit_length / 2)):
        # print(i)
        # print(f"number_as_string[i]={number_as_string[i]},"
        #       f" number_as_string[:i]={number_as_string[number_digit_length - i - 1]}")
        if not number_as_string[i] is number_as_string[number_digit_length - i - 1]:
            return False

    return True


def sum_numeric_palindromes(upper_limit):
    """

    :param upper_limit: maximum number
    :return: the sum of all numeric palindrome between 0 and upper_limit (upper_limit not included)
    """

    palindrome_sum = 0
    # upper limit not included
    for i in range(0, upper_limit - 1):
        if is_numeric_palindrome(i):
            palindrome_sum += i

    return palindrome_sum
```

I've tried, with and without counting single digit numbers as palindromes.

I get either 535041 or 534996 but both options are rejected.

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: What answer do you expect to get?  Any ideas where the problem might be?

Comment: no ideas where the problem is :(

Comment: @Caridorc `is` is not weird at all, it is quite straightforward and reasonable semantics, and well-documeted. Of course, if you just **guess** at what it might do, then you might guess wrong. But that doesn't make it "weird".

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Usually people say things like `[1,2,3,4,5] is [1,2,3,4,5]` but this is False in Python. Overall I agree with you, but ergonomics matter and `is` should have been named `is_same_object` to make it clear that is something to be used rarely

Comment: @Caridorc it's clear enough as it is. Again, sure, if you just wildly guess at the semantics of the language, you might be wrong, but this is extremely simple to understand and learn. In any case, this is a matter of opinion, so I don't think we need to hash it out

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yes, your opinion is also reasonable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation of `range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range) you can see that the last item is excluded so the `upper_limit - 1` is a bug, also `is` is a weird operator that does not behave as you expect, use `==` instead in most cases, in your case `!=` (different than) is the best choice. Tell me if the code is correct after fixing both possible sources of the bug.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def is_palindrom(number):
    return str(number) == str(number)[::-1]

def sum_palindroms():
    sum = 0
    for i in range(10000):
        if is_palindrom(i):
            sum += i

    return sum

print(sum_palindroms())
```

Comment: You don't need to check the entire `str(number)` for equality on the whole string/inverse string but only half its length, checking for equality doesn't shortcut when inequality is found, you call `str` twice instead of caching the string, you must preferably not override `sum`, and for some reason you removed the argument from `sum_palindroms`.

Comment: Very concise, I like it very much! but it didn't help me understand what I was doing wrong :/

Comment: @Guimoute it's just checking whether a number is a palindrome, I let my self assume the upper limit is 10,000 so efficiency is not what important here.

Comment: @Guimoute But do you think that that half/shortcut stuff is faster here? Or why do you say that?

Comment: It's just how palindrome work, you never need to test for more than half the length. For example, if you want to test whether `"1231"` is a palindrome you check `if 1 == 1 and 2 == 3`, no need to add `and 3 == 2 and 1 == 1`. If you test 1M number you will feel the difference in terms of performance.

Comment: @Guimoute I agree in general, but in this case it really doesn't matter since the maximum number has 4 digits (9999)